# Interpreting probit results in Stata 

Tags: logistic, stata, probit

I have read the Stata manual but I am still having trouble understanding how to interpret these results. I am looking to determine how each parameter affects the outcome given a 1-unit change.

The code I am using in Stata is as follows:

```
probit hhaffbyinvest ///
femintmig femdommig maleintmig maledommig ///
femeduc maleeduc lifecycl ///
fmeduc members ratio_workers ///
hmale ///
commun1 commun2 ///
if (fem1stmig >= 1991 | male1stmig >= 1991) & (femhomenow == 1 | malehomenow == 1) ///
& country == 8

est store guat
```

*hhaffbyinvest* is whether a household has reported investing remittances. The line below that is the migration experiences of male and female heads of household, then education, lifecycle of household, size of household, etc...

I am running this in three countries. The results I get are as follows:

[image: probit analysis]

So, for example, how do I interpret 1.4275 for *femintmig* (a female head or spouse migrated internationally) with respect to the binary dependent variable (household invested remittances)?  This is the first column in Guatemala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as to interpret the results of a `probit` model, you have to compute the marginal effects.  The marginal effect of an independent variable is the change in the probability of observing a certain outcome, if the independent variable changes by one unit, whereas all the other variables remain constant. In Stata, marginal effects can be computed via the `margins` command.

Have a look a the following model, which explains union membership by the worker's age, the fact of being married and the fact of having a college degree:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
probit union age i.married i.collgrad
margins, dydx(*)
```

You will end up with the following output:

```
Average marginal effects                          Number of obs   =       1878
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(union), predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : age 1.married 1.collgrad

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         age |   .0014378   .0032566     0.44   0.659     -.004945    .0078207
   1.married |  -.0469362   .0210713    -2.23   0.026    -.0882352   -.0056372
  1.collgrad |   .0978039   .0242385     4.04   0.000     .0502973    .1453105
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

This means that if age increases by 1 year, the probability of being a union member will increase by 0.0014378  * 100 = 0.14378 percentage points. Being married decreases the probability of union membership by -4.69362 percentage points and having a college degree  increases the probability by 9.78039 percentage points.

Comment: Does this also mean that a married college graduate that is one year older will increase the probability by 5.23055 (9.78039 - 4.69362 + 0.14378)?

Comment: No. I have edited my response. Marginal effects have a "ceteris paribus" interpretation. They tell what happens if a given variable varies, while all the other variables remain unchanged.

Comment: I can't read Stata, but it's worth noting that the change in probability *cannot* be constant regardless of the starting point for a covariate in probit regression. Eg, the change in probability from 1 to 2, will not = the change in p from 2 to 3. Rather, a one-unit change in a covariate will change beta z's; computing the cdf at the before & after z's, & subtracting will give you the change in probability associated w/ moving b/t *those two specific covariate values*. I find this answer a little confusingly worded in that it makes it seem the effect on the probability is constant.

Comment: @gung. Good comment but (if remember correctly) these are the marginal effects at the means of the variables

Answer (score 1):

In an OLS model, the marginal effect is the same for each observation (in particular, the marginal effect is the coefficient on the dummy variable).  But in a nonlinear model -- including Probit -- the marginal effect is conditional on the X's of the particular observation.

Think about the underlying predicted values.  When calculating a predicted value from a Probit regression, the coefficients you see get multiplied by the respective X's (for each observation) and added. Then, the "X_i * b" gets put into the Probit function.

For intuition on how the marginal effect works, do the following:

1. Run your probit model
2. `predict yhat`
3. `replace femintmig=0` (perhaps making a backup first)
4. `predict yhat0`
5. `replace femintmig=1`
6. `predict yhat1`
7. `gen margeffect = yhat1 - yhat0`
8. `browse yhat* margeffect`

Now, the key issue is how to turn the column of `margeffect` observations into a single number for you to put into a table or report.  This is a matter of interpretation/application to your specific case.  There is no "right way" to do it.

lejohn's solution takes the average of the `margeffect` column.  Another option is to calculate the mean of each X.  Then calculate the marginal effect at "X bar" (which is what the old `mfx` command used to do).

Comment: Note that ``margins`` can be used to calculate the marginal effect at the mean of each x variable: ``margins, dydx(*) atmeans`` . However, this might not be quite meaningful for qualitative variables. More generally, with the ``at()`` option you can fix the x variables at any arbitrary value.